# blocking url loader

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need to load some images at run time,  but I can't use events as I have a code block like this:

```
loader.load(request);
//do something with loaded resource
```

I'd like to avoid an active wait with a

```
  while (condition) <sleep>
```

cycle...isn't there a way to make load() method blocking?

Comment: Do you mean non-blocking? Blocking, by definition, forces you to wait until the activity is done to move to the next step in your script... Not quite sure you're being clear about what your goal is, here. Do you want to load images at run time, but force the user to wait until the images are loaded to proceed onward, or do you want to load images at run time, and you don't care which is loaded first or when?

Comment: It may not be the best of ideas to not allow the user to do something just because images are loading.

Comment: I want blocking: if loader.load() doesn't block (like it's now) the following instructions fail because of null variables

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use events for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't. Flash is non blocking by nature. Being single-threaded, this is the only way to allow the application to respond to user events and update the screen while doing I/O. 
Even though Workers were added to the lastest versions of the Flash Player, they still don't allow you do synchronous stuff like that.